# How to apply styles only after page is fully loaded in nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a navbar that needs to be transparent only in homePage. The problem i am facing is that, when i click to go to the homepage, the styles are applied instantly, before the homepage is loaded. This results in an ugly navbar for a few miliseconds before the homepage is displayed. How can i apply 'transparency' only AFTER the homepage actually displayed?

Currently i have a computed method called homePage that returns true if that's the case. And i use a style binding to apply the 'transparency' class if the condition is true:

```
<nuxt-link aria-label="home-page" to="/" class="d-flex">
            <v-img
              :src="require('~/assets/images/example.svg')"
              max-height="55px"
              max-width="110px"
              class="mb-1"
              :class="{ 'transparency': homePage }"
              contain
            ></v-img>
          </nuxt-link>
```

in script:

```
homePage() {
      if (this.$route.path === '/') {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    },
```

Comment: I would use a store, and then set what the transparency should be in the created (on) / beforeDestroy (off) hooks of the page, your going to have reactivity issues watching the route

Answer (score 0):

Use `mounted` hook from Vue.js ([see docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#registering-lifecycle-hooks)). Just have a reactive variable and toggle it when mount is completed.

I believe from the code you're using Options API, so it should be:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      homePage: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.homePage = true
  }
}
</script>
```

Demo showing conditionally applied red font color [HERE](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9ks9uwjAMxl/FygkkSIFjV5D2BjvsmEvWGlqUNlHsbkNV330u/cPQpElVky9OfrE/p1OvIejPFlWqMspjFfhkGvwOPjIUeLatY+hMA1BYtqv1OAeIyG1sZgVQ+hrf7AVTOFtHOC73w9Bvhn/t24axeABy35B3qJ2/rIyawkat/0a5rEjP/PV43biLkN+rGn3LKwEfT490nukHklKcvS14gCcoHIFjOyX93+VTWRs47Ha7u5IS5cuSxToRjHVwllEUQFbuIc2dJToa1UUs0sWr3qhT1y0S+j5Lyr2cypJfCJHENzfStAAeDjofU+lE8TJlImlMO9VGVfXQw21tg76Sb6S/93NmCpBR6UwySh7AoI0qmQOlSULnfHgVV9I+XhKZ6SgdErM1Ur39iP6LMArYqNkF1f8Atd7A7Q==)
(I added 2s delay into `mounted` hook, so it is clear it takes effect)

Comment: the nav would only be mounted once

Comment: mounted doesn't exist in server side rendering. am i wrong?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone well, you should check whether your homepage component is mounted, not just the initial mount of the navbar - I believe this happens everytime you click "go to homepage"... Also thinking about it - maybe you should load your styles in app.vue or in nuxt.config.js, so you load them only once and not everytime you visit homepage. Or? Maybe I need to see more of your code to understand your needs...

Comment: @Kos-Mos I don't think so. Even with `ssr: true` you can call `mounted` in your components and get it correctly invoked. I just tested it in StackBlitz for both Nuxt 2 and 3. Maybe you meant `ssg` - static site generation? Here it would be true, I guess, since the output is static pre-rendered html/js with no reactivity.